# "cannot write file in SD card" when taking a screenshot

Tags: sd-card, screenshots, lg

I have an Optimus Black.

When I try to take a screenshot, it makes a noise. Then, it says `cannot write file in SD card`.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe inserting a SDCard? Or setting the camera to save to internal storage? You will need to provide some more details for better answers :)